# Как сделать выборку WP_query на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-query

Есть кастомный тип записи "Врачи", мне необходимо на странице врача сделать выборку по метаполю с помощью wp_query. Делала на других страницах - проблем не было, а тут не работает((( Видимо я чего-то не понимаю. Есть, например, кастомный тип записи "Заболевания", и когда мне в нем нужно было сделать выборку врачей я применила такой код:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type' => 'doctors',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'meta_key' => 'doctor_departments',
                            'meta_value' => $podpis_departments[0]
                        ) );
```

где в переменной $podpis_departments[0] лежит id поля doctor_departments.
Делаю выборку по врачам на странице врача

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'doctors',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'meta_key' => 'doctor_departments',
                        'meta_value' => $current_term_doctors
                    );
```

где в переменной $current_term_doctors лежит id поля doctor_departments, но выборка не происходит, если пишу в posts_per_page 10, то нормально выдаются первые 10 врачей.

Подскажите, что делаю не так.

Comment: Что такое `doctor_departments` и как оно хранится? В `$current_term_doctors`, массив/строка/число?

Comment: doctor_departments это поле acf, в $current_term_doctors массив

Comment: прошу прощения $current_term_doctors - это строка

Comment: "поле acf", -- а какое именно ACF поле?

Comment: тип поля таксономия, возвращает id

Comment: В поле таксономия выбирается одна или несколько?

Comment: Выбирается несколько

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147930/discussion-between-simon-and--).